# Efficient way to generate random numbers with weights

Tags: c++, random

I need to frequently generate a large number of random numbers in my project, so I am seeking an efficient way to do this. I have tried two ways: (i) using `random()` and `srand()`; (ii) using C++ `random` library.

I tried on the following example: I need to generate 100000000 numbers, from {0, 1, 2, 3}, with weights {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4}. And from the example, I found that (i) is faster than (ii). (i) requires ~1.3s while (ii) requires ~4s, both using release builds. Is there **any other more efficient way** to generate random numbers with weights? This is exactly the bottleneck of my program.

Note that, this is just an example. The codes inside the loop in the example are just part of the codes inside the loop in my program. For example, each time generating random numbers has different `weights` so it seems that I cannot move `std::discrete_distribution` outside the loop. I just want to repeat the code and see the execution time.

(i) Using `random()` and `srand()`

```
    vector<int> res;
    res.resize(100000000);
    vector<double> weights{0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4};

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i) {

        double tempSum = 0;
        double randomNnm = (double)(random()/(double)RAND_MAX);

        for(int j = 0;j < weights.size(); j++) {
            tempSum += weights[j];
            if(randomNnm <= tempSum) {
                res[i] = j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

(ii) Using C++ `random` library

```
    vector<int> res;
    res.resize(100000000);
    vector<double> weights{0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4};

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i) {
        unsigned seed = chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
        default_random_engine randGen(seed);
        discrete_distribution<int> thisDistribution(weights.begin(), weights.end());
        res[i] = thisDistribution(randGen); // get the final value
    }
```

Comment: srand/rand is definitely not random :)

Comment: Your second (ii) version is seeding and allocating/freeing a lot of memory on the stack every loop. Please also move those outside the loop and compare again.

Comment: You mean `rand` and `srand`. In the C++ part, you are not supposed to recreate the engine in every loop iteration. Seed it once and use it repeatedly with a distribution.

Comment: Also remember to to tell us how you compiled the test, how you measured and that they were both release builds.

Comment: @0___________ For some definition of random, it is.

Comment: *I found that (i) is much faster than (ii). (i) requires ~1.9s while (ii) requires ~33.4s* -- Are you timing a non-optimized build (debug build), or an optimized, release build?  If it is an unoptimized build, then the timings you are showing are meaningless.  Please post the build settings for your application.

Comment: No wonder the second approach is that slow. `std::discrete_distribution` is not supposed to be created each time a random number is needed, it is supposed to be created only *once*.

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks. I forgot to change back to release build. Now  (i) runs ~1.3s and (ii) 4s.

Comment: Thanks for the comments on moving something outside the loop. But in my case, those inside the loop are just part of the code inside the loop. Each time it has different ```weights```. So I just want to repeat the code and see the execution time.

Comment: @Joxixi If `weights` change between each iteration, you need to model that in both versions.

Comment: The code is simply wrong. An RNG is meant to be seeded only once, then it generates a sequence of random numbers. The same seed will produce the same sequence, which means your code is already producing duplicate numbers because it's seeded with the same time value.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other way to efficiently generate random numbers?

Comment: @Joxixi How do the weights change exactly? I'm beginning to doubt that the random number generation or the distribution are the bottlenecks. An LCG is very fast, and I don't think the distribution speed can be improved.

Comment: @Nelfeal The weights are related to the probability tables of a Bayesian Network, and they are updated gradually, so I cannot say exactly how they change. This part really takes a big proportion of time because it runs frequently, and I have optimized the other part inside the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `random` library correctly. In the C version, you put the call to `srand` outside of the loop, so do the same in the C++ version for the engine and the distribution.

```
std::vector<int> res(100000000);
std::vector<double> weights{0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4};
std::default_random_engine randGen(seed);
std::discrete_distribution<int> thisDistribution(weights.begin(), weights.end());

for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    res[i] = thisDistribution(randGen);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5nzqrd9jG)

Timing this code (online, so it might not be accurate), I find the C++ version to be only slightly slower than the C version.

Comment: From [https://quick-bench.com/](https://quick-bench.com/q/2uiilUfS5tQ76KAJzLvGKYez-xw), it is 4.4 slower with clang (gcc does better, 1.3 slower [Demo](https://quick-bench.com/q/LG5CEHh4eONFgG-15hy6SGp_30w)) :-/ (I don't know if quality of result differs though).

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for the links. Clang with its own libc++ seems to perform best ([demo](https://quick-bench.com/q/ROmO_zw702ut6quQozA1qSwDsZc)).